# Symfony2 Form + AngularJS for REST API = Form validation extra fields error

Tags: php, angularjs, rest, symfony

I've read this article (http://welcometothebundle.com/symfony2-rest-api-the-best-2013-way/) to build my system REST API with Symfony2. Following the guide, i no longer use Symfony2 Form as web form but only 2 main job: **map data into Entity** and **Validation**. In my view, i'm using AngularJS to call REST API with the help from its good built-in services.

In my case, I want to update my entity, AngularJS will get JSON data which serialized from entity and set back to $scope.object to bind to form. For example:

```
{
    email: "bill.gates@testsite.com"
    id: 22
    party: {
        id:24,
        lastName: Gates,
        firstName: Bill
    }
}
```

Make some change then send $scope.object to update route with PUT method, I will use Symfony2 form and submit this data, but Symfony2 form validation keep throwing exception **This form should not contain extra fields.**. I know **id** field is not a form field but don't know how to make Symfony to ignore all these extra fields. Can you help me?

Comment: The form param name given in Symfony form doesn't match the field name of JSON. Symfony form usually have myform[email] myform[id]. So the form handler won't catch the correct field name but putting those to extra fields. BTW, I'm working in an org developing on top of AngularJS + Symfony2. In our app, When we want to POST /some_url, we use JSON de-serialization provided by JMSSerializerBundle. You can take a look on that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `id` field is not a form field, then you can add that to your form but add it as a non-mapped field (i.e. it doesn't relate to a property on the entity):

```
$builder->add('id', 'hidden', array('mapped' => false));
```

Comment: I'm looking for something to ignore form extra which mentioned here https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/7209. But maybe yours is the only way to solve this problem at this time. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

From Symfony version `2.6` you can use new form option `allow_extra_fields` ([accepted pull request](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/8133)). `2.6` release [is planned](http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/community/releases.html#schedule) on 11/2014 but you can use it already (in `composer.json`):

```
"symfony/symfony": "2.6.*@dev"
```

Comment: That's great news, upvoting. In the nearest future, this will be the best answer.

Comment: Using dev versions is never encouraging, but yes, this should now be available in 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions:

1. You can unset the field `id` and modify the request data before you pass the data array to the form, so that it fits to your form. In your case I assume it must be:

   ```
   $data = $request->request->all(); // get all posted data
   unset($data['id']);
   $data['party'] = $data['party']['id'];

   $form->submit($data);
   ```
2. You can add the field to your form type or to the form builder and set the `mapped`-option to `false`, so that Symfony does not try to map it to your entity. Like @JamesHalsall already mentioned.